# Calling jQuery functions dynamically in a HTML5 Responsive layout

Tags: jquery, html5-video

I am working with a responsive theme (Omega) in Drupal which detects browser size and changes the page layout based on CSS provided for certain screen sizes (700px+, 900px+ and 1100px+).

It does this I believe by adding media queries and/or adding css classes to the body tag.

I have a slightly varying function that I want called in reaction to browser window size changes, but it has to be responsive, I.E. calls the relative function without a page reload

Can this be done?

**I currently have something like this:**

```
$(window).resize(function(){
 var width = $("body").width();
   if(width>1100)
     { 

                        $('.accordion').gridAccordion({width:1160, height:526, columns:4, distance:2, closedPanelWidth:50, closedPanelHeight:50, alignType:'centerCenter', slideshow:true,
                        panelProperties:{

                        }});

     }


      if(width>900)
     { 

                    $('.accordion').gridAccordion({width:920, height:417, columns:4, distance:2, closedPanelWidth:50, closedPanelHeight:50, alignType:'centerCenter', slideshow:true,
                    panelProperties:{

                    }});

     }
```

});

The problem with this is it doesn't load my div until I resize the window, and it also requires a refresh before it recognises the window has been resized.

I appreciate any help I can get on this, thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

So I've modified my code to look like this

`$(window).bind('resize load',function(){
     var width = $("#zone-header").width();
            if(width>1100)...`

This now has now fixed the issue with the div not loading right away, but it still doesn't fix my resizing issue unless I resize and then refresh the page. I can't help but feel that I'm so close to a resolution, but just don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

The not being called initially can easily be solved by simply calling it yourself initially:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    // stuff
}).resize();  // fire the resize
```

As far as needing to refresh the screen, that should not be the case.  I would suspect the issue is with plugin you are using not working properly if called multiple times, but I am unfamiliar with that plugin.

Comment: The plug-in I am using is this 

http://codecanyon.net/item/grid-accordion/full_screen_preview/141991

I'm not that hot with jQuery and have asked the plug-in writer if he had a responsive version but he's said it's currently only in production

Comment: I've made some changes to the code as detailed above but it still hasn't fully resolved my issue, would you be able to provide a little more assistance? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not really sure what else I can do.  Many plugins do not work correctly if applied twice.  The only workarounds aside from modifying the plugin, are pretty bad.  You can keep a copy of the original `.accordion`, then each time, remove the one the pluggin is attached to, clone the original and reattach the pluggin.  Or you can try to figure out everything the plugin does, reverse it, then reapply.  all bad options.